# Is it possible to alt+space instead of ~ to produce a non-breaking space in LaTeX on osx?

Tags: spacing, mac

I learnt recently that `alt+space` produces a non-breakable space on macs, and I would like to be able to use it with LaTeX, if possible. Here is the error I get so far:

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:  not set up for use with
>   LaTeX.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
En Français, on met une espace devant :% the non-breakable space is before the ":"
les deux points.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would warn against using such invisible characters. You'd have difficulties identifying them in your document on a later occasion. Why won't you use ``~``?

Comment: While TeX allows the comfort of a visible tie-in, I do encourage to get into the habit of using the alt+space in other programs. Identifying them is just a `/ /` away. The World is riddled with documents and websites and whatnot which have, for example, `10 000` without unbreakable space between the numbers. So the intention of making the number easier to read can go topsy-turvy (and often does) if the line break happens there.

Comment: @Sverre One might argue that a good editor/word processor should display special spaces in a special way. I don’t know if this is commonly done, however. TeXstudio, Texmaker, TeXworks and TeXnicCenter don’t seem to.

Comment: @doncherry I'm not sure if any editor does. Even Notepad++, which distinguishes between ``000A`` (line feed) and ``000D`` (carriage return) makes no distinction between ``00A0`` and ``0020``.

Comment: @morbusg Just to be nit-picking, the thousands separator should be a non-breakable _thin_ space, not a non-breakable regular space.

Comment: @Sverre: Sure, but AFAIK, no “default” keyboard layout (/key mapping) includes a thin space.

Comment: @morbusg Another reason to stick to the ``LaTeX`` conventions ``~`` and ``\,`` :)

Comment: @morbusg The [Neo](http://neo-layout.org/) Layout includes a thin non-breakable space in its sixth layer, but that’s not quite a “default” layout.

Comment: @Sverre vim can be made to display non-breaking spaces with e.g. `set listchars=nbsp:␣`.  One advantage of real nbsp over ~ arises when generating latex from some other format, such as restructuredText (where `~` is rendered as `\textasciitilde{}`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the character just needs to be defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{\nobreakspace}
\begin{document}
En Français, on met une espace devant :% the non-breakable space is before the ":"
les deux points.
\end{document}
```

Also `\usepackage[french]{babel}` takes care of the additional spaces before some punctuation characters in French typography.

Comment: @Heido Oberdieck, do you if doing like this will clash with how `babel` managed the spaces? (I think it is ok, since this should be equivalent to `name~: Colas` and I think this does not clash with `babel`)

Comment: @Colas: `frenchb.ldf` removes a previous space (`\unskip`) before setting its own space, thus the spaces are not duplicated.

Comment: Does this space have stretchability/shrinkability?

Comment: @morbusg: `\nobreakspace` is used by `~` and has the same strechabilit/shrinkability as a space or backslash with space (the latter is the space that `\nobreakspace` uses).